# Chrome dev tools console drawer will not go down all the way

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There seems to be some kind of bug with the console drawer. The drawer refuses to go down all the way. When I go the the actual console tab, it will go down all the way.

I am on Windows 10 and latest version of Chrome.

[image]

Comment: I doubt this has something to do with Windows 10.

Comment: Just in case since it seemed to have started only after I upgraded